# LXD: restore the deleted image

Tags: lxd

After creating an lxd container in the ZFS storage I deleted the based image by mistake.

Now the ZFS structure looks like:

```
# zfs list -t all -o name,clones
...
main/containers/mail
...
main/deleted/images/d0...a6e7                                                            
main/deleted/images/d0...a6e7@readonly  main/containers/mail
...
```

How can I restore the deleted based image?

Comment: from backup. How else?

Comment: @djdomi
It is not deleted at all as you can see but moved to the "deleted" section.
I want to correctly restore It to create new containers based on it.
Otherwise I need to reload new image from remote site,  that will be waste of space.

Comment: please tell us how you deleted it